# Amorphous sets and vagueness

Tags: set-theory, properties, vagueness

I'm reading [a detailed study of amorphous sets](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/016800729400024W?ref=pdf_download&fr=RR-2&rr=7e49cc8e3c3f1f49) and this caught my eye:

[image]

With respect to ["epistemicism" about sorites problems](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/sorites-paradox/#EpisTheo), is there some way to correlate the possible (if unidentifiable?) values of *n* for amorphous partitions (per the above quote) with the unknown values of *n* that mark out the transition point for vague predicates? I tried Googling {"amorphous sets" "vagueness"} as well as {"amorphous sets" "sorites"} and got nothing, though.

Comment: hey, a little help, if you can. i am in a suicidal panic.

Comment: @user66697 I'm not licensed for crisis counseling, but I can recommend the 988 line if you're in the US. I'm not sure what similar services are in other countries.

Comment: ok. is that a hint that you know what is happening. i may get sectioned tomorrow. it would be nice to know what i should tell them

Comment: @halp are you in the UK?

Comment: yes. i was banned from emailing the samaritans because i was scaring them idk

Comment: do you know`if i was being followed by a woman called fanny r___ ? i have decided it is unlikely, again, but if that's not the case, and she was, then it will only get worse for me to deny it

Comment: @halp "sectioned" is a mental-health term in the UK, that was my lead. But IDK what the protocol for crisis response is in the UK. I know it to some extent in the US, having contacted 988 multiple times.

Comment: thanks. i spoke to a crisis team, and they said stay off line until timorrow, when i will be assessaed. i'll be ok, as my person, if not my life, is valuable. good luck w. stackexchange ha